# How do you do a sql "like" query using azure mobile sdk in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, sdk

I have seen samples of how to do a simple query in azure table where column equals a certain value, but now i need to do an equivalent of "select where firstname like %abc".

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: This could be an option... http://www.tapanila.net/windows-azure-mobile-services-custom-api-for-existing-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer. To accomplish this, you need to create a new api, and use code similar to this

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
        var id = request.query.id;
        request.service.mssql.query(
        'select * from Users where name Like ?',["%test%"], {
        success: function(results) {
             response.send(200, results);
        }
    });
};
```